# Simulate/ mock 3g/4g data on android phone

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-networking

Not sure if possible, but I want applications to think they are connected via 3g/4g data but really they are being fed that data through a wifi connection. I know this is possible, and easy, on an emulator but I need to do this on a physical device.

Comment: Did you find any solution to achieve this ? If yes, please share the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In project mode you can do this,enter project mode depend on which physical device you use,for example Xiaomi(My device is RedMi 4-Android 6.0).
1. Input `*#*#4636*#*#` in dial pane
2. And then you can choose preferred network type.
[image: picture 1]

[image: picture 2]

Comment: This is for preferred network type. I need to find a way to mock 3g/4g, so applications think they are connected via data(3g/4g) but in reality I'm connected to wifi.